# How to find the intend level using ast python

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I am a complete newbie to python, I read through the documentation on ast python and I am able to get the *line number* of python code using ast node

***Example for fetching Line no of some ast node:***

```
lineno = ast_node.__dict__['lineno']
```

but how to find the *intend level* of the same python code using ast node?
Could someone show some light, please? Any help is appreciated

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: Can you post more of your source code please? What is ast_node?

Comment: why do you need indent level when you have AST ? is `col_offset` not enough?

Comment: @ymonad, This is what I was looking for perfect